# Django admin - Filter foreignKey in an Inline

Tags: django

I have these models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)

class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   country = models.ForeignKey(Country, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='countries', blank=True, null=True)

class Organization(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class Membership(models.Model):
   person= models.ForeignKey(Person, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='people', blank=True, null=True)
   organization= models.ForeignKey(Organization, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='organizations', blank=True, null=True)
```

There are a high number of people (over 1000) that can be members of several organizations.

I have a view in the admin page as follows

```
class MembershipInline(admin.StackedInline ):
   model = Membership
   extra = 1

class OrganizationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [MembershipInline]

admin.site.register(Organization,OrganizationAdmin)
```

Therefore I can manage any organization and see the people that belongs to it. I can also add new people to the organization.

The problem is that the number of people is too high and the list shows too many of them. Is there any way to filter this StackedInline?
For example placing another field in the Inline where a country can be chosen to filter the people that can be added, or a search field to filter the person's name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to work using the option "autocomplete_fields "

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   search_fields = ['country__name','name']

admin.site.register(Person,PersonAdmin)

class MembershipInline(admin.StackedInline ):
   model = Membership
   extra = 1
   autocomplete_fields = ['person',]
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnltU.png)